# MySQL LAST_INSERT_ID() not updating due to AUTO_INCREMENT

Tags: mysql, sql, database, triggers, insert

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [mysql getting last_insert_id() in a trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6499389/mysql-getting-last-insert-id-in-a-trigger)

I have MySQL `TRIGGER` firing `AFTER INSERT ON` a table (`my_table`).

I wish to store the `PRIMARY_KEY` of the row effected by the `TRIGGER` in a variable using:

```
SET  @user_id =  LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

Which is backed by [this stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3837990/last-insert-id-mysql). And seems to be working.

However, each time it stores the value as `0`.

From [this stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10246412/last-insert-id-always-returns-0-rmysql-separate-connection-issue), I believe this is due to the fact that `my_table` is set to `AUTO_INCREMENT`.

```
SET  @user_id =  LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

What is the best practice to overcome this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6499389/mysql-getting-last-insert-id-in-a-trigger

Comment: As @ethrbunny said, this is a dupe. Use new.id instead of last_insert_id().

Comment: If there's no `AUTO_INCREMENT`, `LAST_INSERT_ID()` is pointless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The LAST_INSERT_ID() function returns only autogenerated ID values. If you generated ID itself, then LAST_INSERT_ID() won't return it.

Also, trigger works in another session. But LAST_INSERT_ID() works only for current session - where new ID was inserted, e.g. -

```
-- NULL means that ID will be generated by server
INSERT INTO table1(id) VALUES(NULL);
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
> 1
```

Comment: Thanks!...def worked!